# Python child class attributes won't initialise

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-xarray

I am building a child class inheriting from the xarray Dataset class but I wish to use the xarray open_dataset function to return the instance. The reason for this is that xarray's open_dataset can link to large datasets without loading them to memory as I would have to do when manually initialising a Dataset instance. I do not wish to modify this function and so to get around this I modify the 'new' method for Dataset to return my own class as follows.

```
def open_dataset(nc_file, data_type):
    data_objs = {
        "my_class": MyClass,
    }
    obj = data_objs[data_type]

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls == xr.Dataset:
            return object.__new__(obj)
        return object.__new__(cls)

    xr.Dataset.__new__ = staticmethod(__new__)

    obj = xr.open_dataset(nc_file)
    return obj
```

I can then define my class as follows and am successfully able to obtain MyClass instances from the open_dataset function which have the my_method method accessible and useable.

```
class MyClass(xr.Dataset)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.my_attribute = 1
        print("in the init")


    def my_method(self):
        print("hello!")
```

However, the instances do not have my_attribute initialised. I have checked by adding a print statement that 'init' is being executed and I do get a print out. I therefore don't understand why the attributes in this init are not being initialised.

Comment: How do you call the method and the attribute? Can you show the code?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply replace `Dataset`, i.e. `import xarray.core.dataset; xarray.core.dataset.Dataset = MyClass`. This doesn't require any `__new__` hacks. By the way, why don't you pass `*args, **kwargs` into `__new__`?